# crop multiply images matlab

Tags: image, matlab, crop

Im trying to crop multiply images in my matlab script but i can't get it to work, my code looks like this now:

```
close all
clear all
clc
A= imread('Ring_background_2.jpg');
jpgFiles = dir('*.jpg');
numFiles = length(jpgFiles);
mydata = cell(1,numFiles);
imcrop(A,[101 159 1047 342])
% mydata = zeros(numFiles);
for k = 1:numFiles
    mydata{1,k} = imread(jpgFiles(k).name);
    cropdata{1,k}=imcrop(mydata{1,k},[101 159 1047 342])
end

for k=1:numFiles
    C=imabsdiff(A,cropdata{1,k});
    E= im2bw(C,0.11);
    figure;
    imshow(E);
    s = regionprops(E,'centroid');
    data{k} = reshape([s.Centroid],2,[]).';
end

for k = 1 : numFiles
    csvwrite(sprintf('data%d.csv', k), data{k});
end
```

im trying to crop 'mydata' into 'cropdata' but i get this error:

> Error using checkForSameSizeAndClass (line 12) X and Y must be the
>   same size.
>
> Error in imabsdiff (line 46) checkForSameSizeAndClass(X, Y,
>   mfilename);
>
> Error in imba (line 16)
>       C=imabsdiff(A,cropdata{1,k});

Comment: What class are your images?

Comment: is it possible that some of your images are smaller than `'Ring_background_2.jpg'`?

Comment: It's the exact same cell size and from the same video so the size of the jpg's are also the same

Comment: Check the return values of `size(A)` and `size(cropdata{1,k})`.

Comment: The return values of A and mydata is the same, i can't get any return values for cropdata since it doesn't finish that...